# Auto indentation in PhpStorm like in WebStorm by default

Tags: php, phpstorm, webstorm

Using WebStorm with the default configuration, when I press `delete` in a blank line with some spaces, the whole line is always deleted. Also, if I close a bracket for a function, the code inside is auto-indented.

I've tried to configure PhpStorm (7.1) with such functionalities (`Settings -> Code Style -> General` and `Settings -> Code Style -> PHP`). I thought that I had found it out when I saw `Tabs and Indents -> Smart Tabs`, but selecting those options nothing seems to change.

[image: PhpStorm Tabs and Indents]

How could I get the above behaviour in PhpStorm?

**Edit:**

As @lena has suggested, I looked inside `Editor -> General -> Smart keys`, but doesn't exist any `Reformat block on typing '}'` option and the other stuff is enabled:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you have `Reformat block on typing '}'` enabled in `Settings | Editor | General | Smart keys`. Also, please try playing with `'Backspace | Unindent`' in `Settings | Editor | General | Smart keys`:

- "Disabled' - smart backspace is turned off;
- 'To nearest indent position' - deletes white spaces to nearest indent position, does not jump to the line above;
- 'To proper indent position' - jumps to the line above.

Comment: I've updated my question. The `Reformat block on typing '}'` option doesn't exist.

Comment: @Manolo It exists. But your IDE is too old. Try latest stable version (2016.1 .. which is v11 as compared to your v7)

Comment: Uhm... My license is about to expire, so I'll get the new version soon. Thanks for your help.